# Why does website display properly in iOS only in private browsing?

Tags: css, ios, safari

I have had this problem for awhile now; when accessing the NFT platform site [Foundation](https://foundation.app/) on mobile Safari, the CSS appears to be broken:

[foundation.app website in mobile safari in standard browsing tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaF3h.jpg)

however, in a private tab, it appears fine:

[foundation.app website in mobile safari in private browsing tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHW5o.jpg)

iOS version is 16.4.1 on an iPhone 12 Pro.

This does not appear to be happening on any other sites, as far as I know. Any suggestions would be welcome.

I have tried clearing the history and website data for Safari in my iOS preferences to no avail.

Comment: Most likely a cache issue, nothing we can solve here. If you don't think it is, try to come up with a minimal reproducible example of your code and someone will be able to help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try adding `?v2` at the end of your CSS ressource URL. It will force the browser to fetch for the stylesheet again. See if the issue persists.